# Header.blade component locale switch - LARAVEL 8 (how to?)

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes, setlocale

I am trying to get my locale prefix to work on all my routings.

It generally works but I get this issue where **the header lang buttons are looking for a parameter from a specific page** (I think).

Tags from my header component:

```html
<li><a href="{{ route(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'nl') }}">nl</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ route(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'fr') }}">fr</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ route(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'en') }}">en</a></li>
```

In my header component.

Once I try to open a page based on a variable as route-parameter I get the error:
[routing-error-message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8iG1.png)

Web.php

```php
Route::redirect('/', '/nl');

Route::prefix('/{locale}')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller@showLanding')->name('home');

    Route::get('intenties-van-de-site', 'App\Http\Controllers\IntentionsController@showIntentionsSite')->name('intenties-van-de-site');
    Route::get('intenties-bij-een-ontwerp', 'App\Http\Controllers\IntentionsController@showIntentionsProject')->name('intenties-bij-een-ontwerp');
    Route::get('architectuur', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArchitectureController@showArchitecture')->name('architectuur');

    Route::get('architectuur/{project}',  'App\Http\Controllers\ArchitectureController@showProject')->name('project-title');
});
```

And a snippet from a link to one of those project pages:

```html
<a href="{{ route('project-title', ['project' => '1978-reel-boom', 'locale' => app()->getLocale() ]) }}">
    <img alt="1978 Reel Boom" title="1978 Reel Boom" src="{img url}">
    <p>1978 Reel Boom</p>
</a>
```

Is there a way to fix the header routing?

Thanks in advance!
A rookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Route::CurrentRouteName()` gives you the named route, but you're missing parameters.

You can get the parameters array using `request()->route()->parameters`.

For example, for the url `'/en/architectuur/something'`, dumping `request()->route()->parameters` returns the following array.

```
[
    'lang' => 'en',
    'project' => 'something'
]
```

Then, you'd only need to change the lang key using [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```xml
@foreach (['nl', 'fr', 'en'] as $lang)
  @php($params = array_merge(request()->route()->parameters, ['lang' => $lang]))
  <li>
    <a href="{{ route(Route::CurrentRouteName(), $params) }}">nl</a>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

Or inline if you prefer

```xml
@foreach (['nl', 'fr', 'en'] as $lang)
  <li>
    <a href="{{ route(Route::CurrentRouteName(), array_merge(request()->route()->parameters, ['lang' => $lang])) }}">nl</a>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! tyvm